# Is there a way to slow the elevator down?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have the Ultra-Lift 3000 Extreme and am having a hard time getting some ? Bitizens to the correct Imperial Levels because it moves too quickly and I can't see enough floors in advance to stop in time. Any ideas?  Or, conversely, can I move an Imperial Level without the VIP mover?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot slow down the elevator. But, my strategy with the Imperial levels has been to move the one that I'm interesting in triggering the cut-scene to the bottom. That way you can't miss it.

There is no way to move the Imperial levels without a VIP mover, because you cannot click on the level without it asking you to build something. I find that the movers tend to show up in great quantities, then a dry patch, then back to great quantities.

Comment: That is brilliant! Now I can finally complete those scenes, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

That's a common complaint for the faster elevators, but there is no known way to slow it down. After you click on the call elevator button and discover the target floor, you can cancel out of the elevator movement and scroll down to see which floor it is. That can help if you can't remember where the floor is.